# Relation between the vector space of Fibonacci sequences and $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> **Question:** Let $V$ be the vector space of real sequences over $\mathbb{R}$. If $W$ is the subspace of all Fibonacci sequences (i.e. a sequence $\{a_n\}\in W$ if $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$, for all $n\geq 3$), then determine whether the following statement is true:
>
> Two elements $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ in $W$ are linearly independent **if and only if** the set $B=\{(x_1,x_2), (y_1,y_2)\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

**Proof:** I think the answer is yes. Since any $\tilde{x}=\{x_n\}\in W$ is determined by the first two terms and also can be represented as $\tilde{x}=x_1 \tilde{a}+x_2 \tilde{b}$ for some two fixed linearly independent vectors of $W$ (precisely, $\tilde{a},\tilde{b}\in W$ whose first two terms are $1,0$ and $0,1$ respectively).

So consider the case that $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are linearly dependent. If either $\{x_n\}$ or $\{y_n\}$ is zero then clearly $B$ is linearly dependent and hence cannot be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Assume that bot are non zero. Then there exists a non zero real scalar $c$ such that $\{x_n\}=c\{y_n\}$ and so $(x_1,x_2)=c(y_1,y_2)$. So $B$ cannot be a basis. For the another direction, assume that $B$ is not a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. If any one element of $B$ is zero, say $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, then $\{x_n\}$ is zero and hence $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are dependent. Otherwise, there exists a real scalar $c$ such that $(x_1,x_2)=c(y_1,y_2)$ and hence $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are dependent. Which completes the proof.

I want to know whether my proof is o.k.

Comment: This proof is indeed ok! You might not have learned about isomorphisms of vector spaces yet, but you've essentially proved the following: the maps $f\colon\Bbb R^2\to W$ and $g\colon W\to\Bbb R^2$ given by $f((a,b)) = {}$(the Fibonacci sequence starting with $a,b$) and $g(\{x_n\}) = (x_1,x_2)$ are linear maps and inverses of each other, hence $W$ and $\Bbb R^2$ are isomorphic.

Comment: @ Greg Martin I understand. Thanks for information.